# TabBarController will hide

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

Is there a protocol for TabBarController "will hide" and "will show" actions?
There seems to be none in UITabBarControllerDelegate,UITabBarDelegate
I am asking this because I want to do something when my TabBarController hides on push.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are no such Notifications, how ever in order to register events you will have to toggle visibility of tab bar programmatically.